# Save image to Firebase using FormBuilderImagePicker

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, forms

I want to save XFile file to Firebase using FormBuilderImagePicker but I couldn't progress after a point. Can you help?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:form_builder_image_picker/form_builder_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:uvddy/models/film.dart';
import 'package:uvddy/services/data_services.dart';


class ApiImage {
  final XFile xFile;
  ApiImage({
    required this.xFile,
  });
}

class FilmEkle extends ConsumerWidget {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  FilmEkle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> girilen = {};
    const yaziSekli = TextStyle(fontFamily: "Encode Sans Condensed Thin", letterSpacing: 1);
    bool isSaving = false;
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 150,
            expandedHeight: 100,
            pinned: true,
            title: Text(
              "Film Ekle",
              style: yaziSekli,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: FormBuilder(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            FormBuilderImagePicker(
                              name: 'isim',
                              displayCustomType: (obj) =>
                              obj is ApiImage ? obj.xFile : obj,
                              decoration:
                                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Afis Ekle'),
                              maxImages: 1,
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value?.isNotEmpty != true) {
                                  return 'Afis Ekleyiniz';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                label: Text('Adı', style: yaziSekli),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value?.isNotEmpty != true) {
                                  return 'Film adı giriniz';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (newValue) {
                                girilen['ad'] = newValue;
                              },
                            ),
                            
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                child: const Text('Kaydet'),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (_formKey.currentState
                                          ?.saveAndValidate() ==
                                      true) {
                                    //debugPrint(_formKey.currentState!.value.toString());
                                  }
                                  //await ref.read(dataServiceProvider).filmEkle(Film.fromMap(girilen));
                                  final imagePath = ApiImage(xFile: .....).xFile.path;
                                  await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('film_afis').child('${girilen['ad']}.jpg').putFile(File(imagePath));
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried this way but couldn't go any further. We are able to select an image using FormBuilderImagePicker, but I had trouble getting the file path of the selected image after selecting the image. If I can manage to get the path to the XFile I will handle the Firebase save.